# If there exists a $\phi \in W'$ so $\text{null}(T') = \text{span}(\phi)$, prove that $\text{range}(T) = \text{null}(\phi)$

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems

I've already proven this question, however, my proof is much more complicated than an answer I saw posted on another website. However, I cannot seem to make sense of why the answer on the website is correct.$\DeclareMathOperator{\range}{range}\DeclareMathOperator{\null}{null}\DeclareMathOperator{\span}{span}$

The answer on the [website](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9783319110790-linear-algebra-done-right-third-edtion/115/exercises/28/) uses the key result that $\null(T') = (\range(T))^0$ to conclude:

> If $\null(T') = \span(\phi)$, then using the result above, we get $(\range(T))^0 = \span(\phi)$
>
> This implies that $w \in \range(T)$ **if and only if** $\phi(w) = 0$.

I see how the forward direction of the above “if and only if” is true, in fact, I used it in my proof. However, how is it obvious that $\phi(w) = 0 \implies w \in \range(T)$? In light of my later proof, I see that it is true, but I don't see how we can conclude this right off the bat.

To give you an idea of what I did, my proof first showed that $\range(T) \subseteq \null\phi$ (using the forward direction of bolded “if and only if”), and then used the three facts

$\dim \null(\phi)) = \dim W - 1$

$(\range(T))^0 = \null(T')$

$\dim(U^0) + \dim(U) = \dim(W)$ (where $U$ is any subspace)

to deduce that
$\dim(\range(T)) = \dim(W) - \dim(\range(T))^0  \\ = \dim(W) - \dim(\null(T')) \\ = \dim(W) - 1$

The last equality follows from $\null(T') = \span(\phi)$, which is one-dimensional. I then concluded that since $\dim(\range(T)) = \dim(\null(\phi))$, and  $\range(T) \subseteq \null(\phi)$, they must be equal.

**Notation:**

$W'$ is the dual space of $W$

$T'$ is the dual map of $T$

$U^0$ is the annihilator of $U$